# Load a datatable in php

Tags: php, mysql, datatable

I would like to know the ways to load a sql datatable into php. I mean this.

In .net you execute dataadapter.fill(dataset), and only one call to the database, brings all the data to the web page.

However in php, you usually call mysql_fetch_assoc, that reads row per row from the result set, that generates n reads from the database.

My question is that if is exists some dataadapter.fill in php that allows me to bring all the data from the database with one call

Comment: Looping with `mysql_fetch_assoc` does **not** generate *n* reads from the database.

Comment: Can you post a simple example?

Comment: With PDO you could use [PDOStatement::fetchAll](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this :

```
$final = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      $ar = array('Column1' => $row['Column1'], 'Column2' => $row['Column2']);
      array_push($final, $ar);
    }

return $final;
```

It only queries the database once. All the query results are stored in `$results`. `mysqli_fetch_array()` only fetches one row at a time though.